Chances of X-rays or Gamma rays to cause bit flips
When an X-ray or a gamma ray strikes a memory cell like in DRAM and causes electron-hole pairs to be created due to effects like ionization of electrons or transferring energy into the electrons, is the probability of the X-ray or gamma ray to actually cause the bit flip probabilistic? Like is hitting the right place in the memory cell something deterministic or is it probabilistic due to things being small and uncertain at the quantum level?

Yes it is probabilistic at several different levels. Given an incident number of x-rays per square centimeter, what is the sensitive area of the device and what are the statistics of some x-ray hitting the sensitive area. What is the probability of that x-ray actually transferring energy to an electron. What is the probability that the initial electron produces any more electrons in the sensitive volume. Etc.

So basically even if an attacker wanted to cause a bit flip on my computer, the outcome is pretty much chaotic? Like he really can't control where he can make the X-ray or gamma ray transfer it's energy to

A single specific bit flip? No chance.
